# Disable dropdpwnlist2 if user makes selection in droplist1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

ASP.Net, C#, WebForms
I would like to disable Dropdownlist4 if user makes selection of 'approved' in DropDownList3. I know this has to be done in the Code Behind but I don't know the syntax. Can someone provide?

```
  <tr>
                        <td>Approve this Request</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Width="250px">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="approved">Approve</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Deny this Request</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Width="250px">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="approve">Deny</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: It's important to add that the DropDownList are inside a FoemView. I know that some logic must be in place with FindControl to get to anything contained in anything in FormView1. Please take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved with the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, minimum example:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        Name:
        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            runat="server" Width="250px" 
            AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="approved">Approve</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Width="250px">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="approve">Deny</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

**C# Code Behind:**
EDIT: The solution here is to get the `DropDownList` that triggered the event from the `sender` object and then using `FindControl` to get the nested `DropDownList` to disable

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    if (ddl.SelectedValue.Equals("approved", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var ddlTemp = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("DropDownList4");
        ddlTemp.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no doubt @kshkarin the solution will work. How do I get it to work if the dropdownlist are inside a FormView. I get this error message. DropDownList3 does not exist in the current context. I tried the following with no luck.

Comment: protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, object Dropdownlist3)
        {
            DropDownList MyDropDown = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("DropDownList3");
            {
                if (DropDownList3.SelectedValue.Equals("approved", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

Comment: Doesn't work. I think none of it works as anyone would expect. I will just simply create a Separate Page for Approvals and another page for Deny and use this approach for the remainder of the application to save time.

Comment: Are both dropdowns inside the FormView control? Which section are they in - `EditItemTemplate` or `ItemTemplate` or other? Please edit the question with more details about the aspx page structure

Comment: they are in the Edit Mode, EditItemTemplate.

Comment: Please check the answer edit, added `FormView` and how to deal with nested controls and how to use `FindControl`.

Comment: No worries! My workaround solution is cleaner and easier.

Comment: @user2209864 so why not post the workaround to help future readers?

Comment: I will post it today. I have been swamped with trying to finish this project but I will get it posted today.